# Understanding join() method of Thread

Tags: java, multithreading

I think I understand what `Thread.join()` means but I want to be sure:

When code running in `threadA` calls `join()` on the object `threadB`, the code pauses execution until `threadB` is done executing - i.e. exited it's `run()` method.

For example:

```
void someCode(){
    threadB.start(); // threadB was instantiated elsewhere
    threadB.join();
    System.out.println("threadB has exited it's run() method.");
}
```

Calling `threadB.join()` makes the thread running this line of code, wait until `threadB` is finished before moving to the next line of code.

Correct?

Comment: Your question is already answered by the [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#join()).

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not really a question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that is correct. If the thread corresponding to the `Thread` object you called `join` on has already terminated, the method returns immediately.

Comment: Cool thanks. Will accept your answer in several minutes.